# Sorting objects in NSMutableArray with sortUsingComparator

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, compare

I have the following mutable array:

```
NSMutableArray *persons = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:person1, person2, person3, nil];
```

where every person is an object, which contains (NSInteger) personAge and (NSString*) personName properties.
Now I want to sort this array by personAge. So I tried the following:

```
[persons sortUsingComparator:
     ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
     {
         Person *p1 = (Person*)obj1;
         Person *p2 = (Person*)obj2;

        return [p1.personAge compare: p2.personAge];

     }];

    NSLog(@"%ld", [persons componentsJoinedByString:@" "]);
```

But I'm getting a "Bad receiver type 'NSInteger' (aka 'long')" error message in the return line. Also I have a warning in the NSLog line: "Format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'NSString *'". How do I fix it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Shouldn't you use something like this instead?

```objectivec
[persons sortUsingComparator:
    ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        Person *p1 = (Person*)obj1;
        Person *p2 = (Person*)obj2;

        if (p1.personAge > p2.personAge) {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
        }

        if (p1.personAge < p2.personAge) {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
        }

        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }
];
```

The thing is that you have rely on the `compare` method which doesn't exist on `NSInteger`: it is only a typedef of `int`. So you want to compare integer value instead and returns an `NSComparisonResult` value to denote the ordering of your object accordingly.

Comment: Yep, same result as in the above answer: <Person: 0x10010a720> <Person: 0x10010ad20> <Person: 0x100108ab0> And the same question: Is there any way that instead of Person: xxxxxxx I would get the actual personAge? So it would look something like that: 1, 27, 34 etc..?

Comment: [p1.personAge intValue] I think you are printing your NSNumber object

Comment: OK, I'm confused now... Did you mean I should do something like that: `if ([p1.personAge intValue] > [p2.personAge intValue]) {
                 return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
             }`? Then I'm still getting the "Bad receiver..." error. Still have no idea how to print the age of each person...

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear you just need to do a NSLog with the right format: NSLog(@"Age: %d", p1.personAge)

Comment: forget about my comment with the NSNumber object, you are using NSInteger, it is a typedef of an integer

Comment: Nop, I tried that NSLog with the %ld (inside of the ^NSComparisonResult block, since p1.personAge isn't recognized outside of it) and I didn't get any result at all.

Comment: Because %d is for int, while NSInteger is a long int, %d just doesn't work for NSInteger...

Comment: it depends of your system...don't make assumption

Comment: XCode itself suggested me to change it to %ld :)

Comment: yes cuz you are on a 64 bit system...https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html read the NSInteger section

Comment: Yep... Well, I still can't make it to print the personAge, no matter what I try... Very weird... :-/

Comment: I bet you are still using componentsJoinedByString method

Comment: You need to access to personPage for each element of your array: [[persons valueForKey:@"personAge"] componentsJoinedByString:@" "] will do

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to call `compare:` on an `NSInteger`, which is not an object; it's a typedef for an integer type (either `int` or `long` depending on architecture).

Also, `componentsJoinedByString:` returns an `NSString`, not an integer.

Try:

```
[persons sortUsingComparator:
    ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
    {
        Person *p1 = (Person*)obj1;
        Person *p2 = (Person*)obj2;

        if (p1.personAge < p2.personAge)
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        if (p1.personAge > p2.personAge)
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        return NSOrderedSame;
 }];

NSLog(@"%@", [persons componentsJoinedByString:@" "]);
```

Comment: I tried it and I got this result: <Person: 0x10010a720> <Person: 0x10010ad20> <Person: 0x100108ab0> Is there any way that instead of Person: xxxxxxx I would get the actual personAge? So it would look something like that: 1, 27, 34 etc..?

Comment: [[persons valueForKey:@"personAge"] componentsJoinedByString:@" "]

Comment: @Igal, you could also write a description method in your Person class, so that when you do NSLog(@"%@",aPerson), you get something like: "name:Bill, age:26" instead of <Person: 0x10010a720>.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the "Bad receiver type..." error, `NSInteger` is a primitive data type (not an Objective-C class) so you can't call methods on it. what you want to do is the following:

```
if (p1.personAge > p2.personAge) {
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
}

if (p1.personAge < p2.personAge) {
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
}
return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
```

The warning is due to the fact that `@"%ld"` is the format string for a long (as the warning says), but `-componentsSeparatedByString:` returns an `NSString` object. The correct format string for any Objective-C object is `@"%@"`, so the line should read `NSLog(@"%@", [persons componentsJoinedByString:@" "]);`.

Comment: Is there any way that I could get the actual personAge? So it would look something like that: 1, 27, 34 etc.. instead of Person: xxxxxxx in the result?

Comment: Easiest way is to override the `-description` method in your `Person` class to return what you want it to display as.

Answer (score 0):

```
[YOURMutableArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Comment: While this may in fact answer the question, can you elaborate on what this code actually does?

Answer (score 0):

Like tigeguero's answer but tidier:

```
 [people sortUsingComparator:
      ^NSComparisonResult(Person* p1, Person* p2){

            if (p1.personAge > p2.personAge) {
                return NSOrderedDescending;
            }
            else if (p1.personAge < p2.personAge) {
                return NSOrderedAscending;
            }
            else{
                return NSOrderedSame;
            } 
    }
 ];
```